# iTerm2: How to expand split pane temporarily?

Tags: iterm

Is there a way to temporarily expand a split pane into full tab and go back again when done?
I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to do so. The use case is to be able to temporarily switch to full-screen on demand.

Comment: @rizidoro is right! Cmd+Shift+Enter = temp fullscreen

Comment: Life-changer. Also good to know: Cmd+Enter toggles window fullscreen

Answer (score 271, accepted):

To maximize your active panel, just <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the screen you want to expand.

Comment: could I change combination of those keys?

Comment: @Alper Go to Preferences > Keys > Action > Select Menu Item > View > Maximize Active Pane and enter a custom shortcut.

Comment: Maybe things have changed.
iTerm2 - 3.2.8 I had to the following for customization 
Preferences > Keys > '+'  (to add a new action) > Under Action select 'Select Menu Item' > Under view you should see 'Maximize active pane' ..

So basically "Select Menu item" is the Menu items displayed for iTerm and you can customize any of those .

Answer (score 7):

You can maximise and minimise your current panel by using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

There are a lot of hot keys to remember and when starting out it can be helpful to print out a cheat sheet or to scan [the documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html) with `find` in your browser.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I cannot find menu section `Preferences > Keys > Action > Select Menu Item > View > Maximize Active Pane`

My workaround is right clicking on the pane, and select `Move Session to Window` and maximize that window.

We can then `Move Session to Pane` to move it back.

Comment: Its not that easy to find. `Select Menu Item` is an entry in the combobox which reveals an additional combobox on activation.

Comment: The menu section is different in iTerm2 as of April 2022. An up-to-date answer is in comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243933/iterm2-how-to-expand-split-pane-temporarily#comment98057836_16483592.

Answer (score 4):

1. To maximize the active panel with full window, just `Cmd + Shift + Enter`.
2. Then toggle fullscreen with `Cmd + Enter`.

(This also works in iTerm2 3.4 Integrate with tmux.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to double click on the panel title, it will expand. Double click again to reduce it